# Parse Push Notifications without the notification

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

Reading the [Docs](https://www.parse.com/docs/push_guide#top/Android) on `Parse.com` I can't find a way to receive the push message **without showing the default notification**. I'd like to get the message (a `JSON`), do some work with it, then (if necessary) prepare a custom notification with it.
Is it possible? I don't see why it shouldn't, but the Docs aren't clear about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right on both accounts - the Docs could use a bit more detail, and it is possible.

First, in order to provide your own logic implementation you need to create your own broadcast receiver class extend `ParsePushBroadcastReceiver`. When doing this you must update your Manifest file and point the `<receiver>` to your class instead of the `ParsePushBroadcastReceiver`.

In your newly created class, the `getNotification()` method is responsible for creating the notification. Override it to return `null` when you don't want to display a notification, or create your own `Notification` and return it or call the `super` implementation for the default `Notification` if you so desire.

You have many other "hooks" (overridable methods) to perform your logic when receiving the push, each receiving a `Context` and an `Intent` as parameters. In each of these methods you can get your `JSON` data, simply call:

```
JSONObject notificationData = new JSONObject(intent.getStringExtra(KEY_PUSH_DATA));
```

Comment: but if app is in foreground then show notification inside app with cutom textview ...while if user is not using our app then show notification on notification bar how to achive this ?

Comment: You can override the `getNotification` method to return null if you do not want to display a notification.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by creating your own BroadcastReceiver to filter parse's actions. To do that, you need to replace ParsePushBroadcastReceiver with your own receiver (NotiReceiver for in that case). For example ..

In AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver
    android:name=".NotiReceiver"
    android:exported="false" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
    </intent-filter>
```

In your NotiReceiver,

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action.equals("com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE")) { 
        Log.i("Data : ", intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));
    }
}
```

Hope it will be useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the lifecycle of the notification you will find it is still possible to achieve what you want without having to do much of your own implementation.  The easiest and most basic way to take control over the push notifications (specifically to show them or not show them) is to override the `onReceive` method of a `ParsePushBroadcastReceiver`.  If you call `super.onReceive()` then the notification will continue the lifecycle of the notification and be displayed - if you don't call `super.onReceive()` then the lifecycle ends and the notification won't be displayed (thus not calling `getNotification()` at all).  The currently-accepted answer has you unnecessarily continuing the lifecycle onto `getNotification()` and returning `null` but if `super.onReceive()` is not called then `getNotification()` won't be either.  Below is a cleaner method to get what you want with less code.

```
public class MyParsePushBroadcastReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (shouldShowNotification){
           super.onReceive(context, intent);
        }
        //proccess the notification without being displayed
   }

   @Override
    protected Notification getNotification(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //this is only called if super.onReceive() is called
        Notification n = super.getNotification(context, intent);
        n.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/some_sound.mp3");
        return n;
    }
}
```

Even though you wish to not display a notification it was also suggested in the currently-accepted answer that you would have to build your own notification which is also unnecessary because are free to customize the notification that Parse SDK provides for you as well before returning it in the `getNotification()` method.  But since you don't want to display anything you don't have to worry about this.  This is included in the example code above.

Comment: but if app is in foreground then show notification inside app with cutom textview ...while if user is not using our app then show notification on notification bar how to achive this ?